# Changed jdeps behavior in OpenJDK 11.0.11 (JDK-8214213)

Tags: java, dependencies, jdeps

### Summary

Our build pipeline has been broken after some machines have updated from JDK `11.0.10-` to JDK `11.0.11+`. This happens due to changed `jdeps` behavior. After some research it became evident, this is likely due to changes introduced with `JDK-8214213`:

- https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-updates-dev/2021-April/005860.html

Assuming we were retrieving dependencies for `sentry-1.7.25.jar`, then our usage of `jdeps` via CLI is as follows:

```
jdeps --list-deps -filter:module --multi-release=11 "..\somePath\sentry-1.7.25.jar
```

The resulting dependency lists look like this:

#### `11.0.10` and below

```
java.base
java.logging
java.naming
```

#### `11.0.11` and above

```
Error: Missing dependencies: classes not found from the module path and classpath.
To suppress this error, use --ignore-missing-deps to continue.

sentry-1.7.25.jar
   io.sentry.event.helper.BasicRemoteAddressResolver  -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
   io.sentry.event.helper.ForwardedAddressResolver    -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
   io.sentry.event.helper.HttpEventBuilderHelper      -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
   io.sentry.event.helper.RemoteAddressResolver       -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
   io.sentry.event.interfaces.HttpInterface           -> javax.servlet.http.Cookie                          not found
   io.sentry.event.interfaces.HttpInterface           -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletContainerInitializer -> javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer          not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletContainerInitializer -> javax.servlet.ServletContext                       not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletContainerInitializer -> javax.servlet.ServletException                     not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletRequestListener     -> javax.servlet.ServletRequest                       not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletRequestListener     -> javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent                  not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletRequestListener     -> javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener               not found
   io.sentry.servlet.SentryServletRequestListener     -> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest              not found
```

---

In order to fix this on OpenJDK `11.0.11+` it's necessary to set `--ignore-missing-deps` when calling `jdeps`. If done, then the output again looks correct again:

```
java.base
java.logging
java.naming
```

#### Question

So I am able to produce the same output with `jdeps` using JDK `11.0.11+` as I was able to do with JDK `11.0.10-`. That being said, this output is used to create a custom runtime and in the description of `JDK-8214213` is explicitely stated:

> Note that a
> custom image is created with the list of modules output by jdeps when
> using the `--ignore-missing-deps` option for a non-modular
> application. Such an application, running on the custom image, might
> fail at runtime when missing dependence errors are suppressed.

From my understanding this means that if there is a transitive dependency involved, where the dependency of a dependency requires a runtime module that is not required by any of the top level dependencies, then this can lead to a custom runtime uncapable of running the application, since the transitive dependency cannot be resolved. In other words, if my application requires dependency `A`, which requires dependency `B` and module `C`, but dependency `B` also requires module `D`, then my application is at risk of encountering runtime errors, since my custom runtime is not being provided with module `D`.

My question now is this, since I am unable to derive it from documentation:

*With JDK `11.0.11+` I can only get the same dependency list output, if `--ignore-missing-deps` is used. Does that mean that...*

- *...`jdeps` was able to resolve transitive dependencies prior to `11.0.11`, but cannot do so anylonger above said version, e.g. because dependency analysis is done differently internally in `jdeps`?*
- *...`jdeps` acted as if it was using `--ignore-missing-deps` prior to `11.0.11` by default, hence if the default changed, `jdeps` is now throwing an error on `11.0.11+`?*
- *...something else is going on?*

The resulting dependency list might be the same, simply because there are a lot of libraries, so most modules are used either way. However I am trying to determine, whether

```
jdeps --list-deps -filter:module --multi-release=11 "..\somePath\sentry-1.7.25.jar (11.0.10)
```

and

```
jdeps --list-deps --ignore-missing-deps -filter:module --multi-release=11 "..\somePath\sentry-1.7.25.jar (11.0.11)
```

behave exactly the same, or whether using `--ignore-missing-deps` introduces a new risk when adding new libraries to our project, as they may at some point require a module that is not part of the current `jdeps`-list.

Bear in mind, to me this is rather a deep-dive into OpenJDK specifics, so if there is faulty terminoogy or problems with my understanding of these scenarios, then feel free to point out and correct them.